# php5-fpm incomplete install - no config file

Tags: server, php, nginx, wordpress, php-fpm

I've set up a server with Ubuntu 11.04 and Nginx + PHP-FPM + Varnish + APC + MySQL + Memcached + WordPress. Everything runs pretty nice, but there is a tiny problem with the PHP-FPM service. Install goes OK after the usual

```
apt-get install php5-fpm
```

But when you start the service, there is a problem with the config file. It seems that comes [from the Debian package](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=601243), that uses [certain directory](http://www.mailrepository.com/ubuntu-bugs.lists.ubuntu.com/msg/3488569/) (/var/www) that it is used there, but not by default in Ubuntu. So each time I restart the service, I get this:

```
# service php5-fpm start
 * Starting PHP5 FPM...
Aug 19 20:57:31.622788 [WARNING] [pool www] pm.start_servers is not set. It's been set to 20.
   ...done.
```

It's looking for a config file that I don't have, or that I have but PHP5-FPM doesn't find.

How to solve the problem? Where do I have to put the right config file for PHP-FPM??

Answer (score 3):

From the OP:

> Looking for more config files I've finally found the one that allows me to set the right parameters. It is
>
> ```
> /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
> ```
>
> There you can find most of the parameters needed to restart PHP-FPM with the settings anyone can need. I've tested it and after the edition of the file the service runs according to the new parameters.